# I would like to generate a jwt for transip api

Tags: python, api, signature, asn.1, sha512

I try to generate a jwt token for connecting to transip api, but can't figure out how to generate as Signature to request one. I would prefer to do it in Python3. How should I do this?

[Api documentation of transip](https://api.transip.nl/rest/docs.html) and see the section of Authentication

Based on the first answer from AKX I did write some code which fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import OpenSSL


key='''-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'''

data=b'{"login": "test-user","nonce": "98475920834"}'

signatue=OpenSSL.crypto.sign(key,data,'sha512')
print (signatue)
```

The error I get is

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./jwt.py", line 37, in
>   
>       signatue=OpenSSL.crypto.sign(key,data,'sha512')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 2825,
>   in sign
>       length = _lib.EVP_PKEY_size(pkey._pkey) AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute '_pkey'

What is going on here???

(p.s. the key is not valid for use anymore but should be still good to go for creating a singnature)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the linked documentation, you can't directly generate the Bearer JWT token required, but you get it from TransIP's API.

> To get an access token, [...] send an HTTP POST request to ’https://api.transip.nl/v6/auth’ with a body containing your login and a nonce (any random string), and a signature header. The signature header should consist of a sha512 asn.1 hash of the full request body. Encrypt this using a private key that was generated in the control panel.

You will need to use PyOpenSSL or another cryptography library to generate the ASN.1 signature, then send the request using e.g. the `requests` library, and then use the token returned.

Comment: It's solved, you helped me to get going. My solution can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554933/signing-for-requesting-a-jwt-to-use-on-an-api-in-python3

Comment: @Jeromba6 Glad I could help!